# Javascript OOP / Classes

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the right and/or best format for it.  Basically, I am trying to develop some custom Javascript classes for use within my site.  I'd like to be able to call them as follows:

```
MasterClass.SubClass.function(params);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: please note that js is not a OOP, the following answers are examples of JS Prototypes

Comment: "JavaScript is an object oriented language, but JavaScript does not use classes." : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: What’s a Master class and a sub-class? It doesn’t look like any OOP I’ve seen.

Comment: @MunMrd: [a programming language can be object-oriented without classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your single line of pseudocode, this fits the bill:

```
var MasterClass = {
    SubClass: {
        myFunction: function(params) {
            // snip
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just so you're aware, this has nothing to do with OOP. These are just nested objects.

Comment: I'm aware ... is there a way to define a constructor for any of these objects?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to form this structure using object literals:

```
MasterClass = {
    SubClass: {
        fn: function(params) {
        }
    }
}
```

When you want to spread this across multiple source files, you could do this:

```
MasterClass = {}
```

Then, in each additional source file:

```
(function(ns) {
    ns.SubClass = {
        fn: function(param) { }
    }
}(MasterClass));
```

Answer (score 0):

just to do things differently you could use prototype as well and not have to type out MasterClass each time

```
 function MasterClass () {
     this.prop = "test"
 }


 function SubClass () {
    this.func = function () {
    return this.prop
   }
}

 SubClass.prototype = new MasterClass()

 var subclass = new SubClass()
 subclass.func() //return "test"
```

Comment: I prefer simple objects myself over constructors - but it's good to know different ways to "skin" javascript